# Fortran IV program with line CALL DATSW(0,K)

Tags: fortran

I am reading an old scientific paper, [A MATHEMATICAL MODEL OF PHYSIOLOGICAL TEMPERATURE REGULATION IN MAN](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19710023925_1971023925.pdf&ei=fKF7UrvtC4WP0AXH-oF4&usg=AFQjCNEeRgdrJx_JKPGEkDdL0nD4e8Bz7Q&sig2=zXf8YbDiBoe5mv7zGtSJvg) and trying to convert the old Fortran program to Matlab.

But I am encountering some problems:

The paper described a program written in FORTRAN. There is two lines with some sort of function **DATSW**:

```
CALL DATSW(0,K)
GO TO (951,950), K
.....
.....
CALL DATSW(1,K)
GO TO (917,1102), K
```

I tried to guess it from the rest of the codes, but its really hard. These two lines of calling `DATSW` function seem to be very important. Can someone please help me?

Comment: That paper is from 1971.   You are working with FORTRAN IV, not FORTRAN 77.   The computed gotos are a tipoff.

Comment: @M.S.B.: I modified the page to say 77 (v1 shows "Old Fortran") without looking at the paper (only looked at it when I saw you mentioned the date just now).

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search lead me to seeing that this exact question was asked on [comp.lang.fortran in 2009](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/PJ9QkB359T8). A second Google search of `datsw fortran` led me to [this code](http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/SOURCES/FORTRAN/simplex/simplex.f) that comments,

> The statement `CALL DATSW(NSSW,JUMP)` returns `JUMP=1` if sense switch number `NSSW` is on, and `JUMP=2` if it is off.

Most of the way down, you can see a dummy version of the code itself.

```
      SUBROUTINE DATSW (NSSW,JUMP)                                              
C                                                                               
C  DUMMY VERSION OF SUBROUTINE DATSW  --  ALL SWITCHES OFF.                     
C                                                                               
C  J. P. CHANDLER, COMPUTER SCIENCE DEPARTMENT,                                 
C     OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY                                                 
C                                                                               
      INTEGER NSSW,JUMP                                                         
C                                                                               
      JUMP=2                                                                    
      RETURN                                                                    
      END
```

It seems this code was meant for you to modify to check the switch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kyle. I am still a bit confused by "switch". What is a switch and why does the program use DATSW to do it?

Comment: The comp.lang.fortran link in the answer explains that `switch` is a reference to punch cards in the first-gen computers, but basically your `DATSW` tells the program which `goto` to follow. With the first `DATSW`, you will get `k=1` as a return and jump to line `951` via the `goto`. With the second call, you will get `k=2` and jump to line `1102`.

Comment: The reason for the subroutine is because you have multiple calls to `DATSW`. It's easier to change 1 line in 1 subroutine called multiple times than to change multiple lines in the main code (and thereby destroying its re-usability).